# Header file is not being created when a new objective-c class is created in xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, header-files

I am trying to create and objective-c class (subclassed UIViewController) with xcode 4.4. I go to File->new and select an objective-c class template under ios/Cocoa Touch. It says that this selection will create "An Objective-C class, with implementation and header files.". But it only creates an implementation file. The implementation file has a #import for the missing header file.

I am using storyboards. I did not select "With XIB for user interface".

Am I doing something wrong? If this is a bug, any suggestions about how to get around it?

Comment: Sounds like you may be missing a file from the templates. Check in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Cocoa Touch/ and see if there's a header file in Objective-C class.xctemplate

Comment: yes, under the directory for UIViewController, the following files are present: ___FILEBASENAME___.h ___FILEBASENAME___.m

Comment: The really strange this is that if I go to Finder and into the directory where the implementation file is, the header file is present. However, xcode is giving me errors saying that it does not exist. If I try to create a header file with the same name, it wants to know if I want to replace the old file.

Comment: ok, I deleted the header file that I saw with Finder. THen I went into xcode and deleted the implementation file. Then I started over and recreated the objective-c class. This time the header file was created. Weird

Comment: Well, I have no idea what happened, but it's good that you solved it. You should post your procedure into an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found a solution. First I deleted the header file that I saw with Finder in the project directory. Then I went into xcode and deleted the implementation file. Then I started over and re-created the objective-c class. This time the header file was created. Weird